# Why does compiler says I'm trying to convert method from void?

Tags: c#, methods, interface

I was trying how Interfaces are working but I couldn't do it. My goal is write "n" for WriteNorM() in writeN class and write "m" for WriteNorM() in writeM class. But when I try it it's saying that "you are trying to convert void into bool!" please help.(btw don't mind class names it's only a test program)

```
class xd
{
    interface Ixd
    {
        void WriteNorM();
    }

    class writeN : Ixd
    {
        public void WriteNorM()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("n");
        }
    }

    class writeM: Ixd
    {
        public void WriteNorM()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("m");
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Ixd D = new writeN();
        Ixd D1 = new writeM();
       
        Console.WriteLine(D.WriteNorM());
        Console.WriteLine(D1.WriteNorM());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline) expects an argument, but `WriteNorM` is defined as

```
void WriteNorM();
```

so it doesn't *return* anything, and you can't pass `void` to a method.

Conceptually a `void` method doesn't return anything, so there's no return value to pass into another method like you're trying to do:

```
Console.WriteLine(D.WriteNorM());  //  is the same as Console.WriteLine(void)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       void
```

---

Changing your code to

```
static void Main()
{
    Ixd D = new writeN();
    Ixd D1 = new writeM();
   
    D.WriteNorM();
    D1.WriteNorM();
}
```

will produce the output you want:

```
n
m
```

---

Alternatively, you could change your interface to have

```
string GetNorM();
```

instead (i.e. `GetNorM` now returns a `string` that you can then pass into `Console.WriteLine`, instead of `void`):

```
class xd
{
    interface Ixd
    {
        string GetNorM();
    }

    class writeN : Ixd
    {
        public string GetNorM()
        {
            return "n";
        }
    }

    class writeM: Ixd
    {
        public string GetNorM()
        {
            return "m";
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Ixd D = new writeN();
        Ixd D1 = new writeM();
       
        Console.WriteLine(D.GetNorM());
        Console.WriteLine(D1.GetNorM());
    }
}
```

Comment: **Not** "will fix the problem and **return**".  It will "Produce Console output".  Not knowing the difference is what got OP to ask this question in the first place.

Comment: @BenVoigt - very good point - "*work*" is a weak word to use in this situation.